How to read float32 .tiff images with GIMP?
I created a float32 .tiff image that represents the magnitude spectrum from an fft. The image is grayscale. The problem is I dont know how to view the image in GIMP as it displays a pure white image.
I have tried normalizing the image and looking at the levels but I never worked with gimp before, or any other profesional image editor, and I am confused.
What are the next steps I should look for?

GIMP by default treats 0 values as black and 1 values as white. So my representation was always white because my values were not in the 0 to 1 range. Normalizing the image beforehand would show the propper magnitude spectrum.
